# List all applications that handle a specified file type

Tags: c#, windows, associations, file-type

Is it possible to list all the applications on a machine that can open a specific file type, using only the files extension?  for example if I have a text file (.txt), I want a list of all applications that can open .txt files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` hive in your registry.  It's all in there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no master list of every application that can open a specific file that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about Windows machines...

You can only go so far as listing the applications that are registered has to able of handling a specific file extension (the same applications that show up when you right click and select "Open With"). This is somewhere in the Windows Registry.

I would suggest you to check on the microsoft documentation, or open your registry and start searching for known extensions.