# find list of available applications that can open particular type file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a program and I want to open a particular file(e.g ".jpg") with available application as Windows shows **Open With** option on right click.

[image]

I tried `os.startfile()`,but it opens only with default application.Also I found some examples from stackoverflow with same titled but none of them works for Windows in Python.Here are those examples links.

- [this is with QT but gives no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49401558/how-to-get-list-of-available-applications-open-with-linux-windows) ,
- [this is for mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051735/list-potential-applications-that-could-open-a-file)
- [this is with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864966/list-all-applications-that-handle-a-specified-file-type)
- [this is for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662334/how-to-get-list-of-programs-which-can-open-a-particular-file-extension-in-linux)

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: You can start from this... http://smileboywtu.github.io/articles/2016/03/13/python-get-system-default-app-related-a-mime-type.html

Comment: yes,i tried from that **get binary list** but it gives error **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'** @musicamante

Comment: That's a standard python type error, and you'll probably need a `b"..."` string, but if you don't explain *where* you get that error it's impossible to help you. The python traceback always gives you the line of the error.

Comment: **file_ext = out.strip().split('=')[-1]** From this line @musicamante

Comment: Have you searched about that error? Popen returns a byte stream, so you either convert that to string using `out.decode()` or use `split(b'=')`.

Comment: Yes,it works bu using `split(b'=')` instead of `split('=')` ,and  gives **path** for a".jpg" is **%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1**.Is this the paths of available Program(s),I think it is for one only.Then what to do with this ?? Somehow Bartek Kobialka's method gives 3 programs.In My PC it is showing 5 programs available with **Open With**. @musicamante

Answer (score 0):

Try to get this information form registry.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqAxi.png)

```
import winreg

access_registry = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None,winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT)
access_key = winreg.OpenKey(access_registry, r".jpg\OpenWithProgids")

for n in range(20):
   try:
      x = winreg.EnumValue(access_key,n)   
      print(x[0])
   except:
      break
```

Registry key with commands to start programs from "Open with..."
[image]

Comment: can u explain how?with code @Bartek Kobialka

Comment: But i dont know C#.Can you write in python @Bartek Kobialka

Comment: This is a python module to deal with registry https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html

Comment: And here some code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227107/python-code-to-read-registry

Comment: any hints?which method and how to use that modules?@Bartek Kobialka

Comment: i dont know the exact directory as mentioned in that example (such as areg,akey etc.) @Bartek Kobialka

Comment: I found only this information and never tried to do this, but it's possible

Comment: Would you care to expand your answer? Right now it's more of a suggestion, and an actual example would be much more welcome and clear to the OP.

Comment: Sorry for not fully answer before

Comment: in my pc options are like the above images but it gives **jpegfile , Microsoft.PhotoManager.imagetype , Opera.Image**.Why it is not matched.And Then the question is how to use this to open that file(i mean ".jpg")??? @Bartek Kobialka

Comment: I think you should find the path to an chosen app and run it using QProcess with parameter represents .jpg file that you want to open. I added a screen shot to the answer with key in registry with commands to start programs with file parameter.

Comment: i didnot get it .how to start.Can you please explain a little bit more? And did you check the link musicamante commented above in my question.?

Comment: If you list all .jpg\OpenWithProgids you can simply find a path to all listed apps using script as above at path HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT search key with name one of listed name. Then go to key shell/open/command and get value. Next u can use whatever you want to create cmd process (for example subprocess.call() as musicamante  wrote) that execute the command for example: ""C:\Users\Roman Szylinski\AppData\Local\Programs\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-2.10.exe" "%1"" where %1 is file to open.

Comment: Your method gives me 3 apps,musicamante suggested link gives one app an My pc shows 5 apps, As you can see.then how can i get others? And could you please write this line codes in you Answer section?